# Python timeit timers - start and stop functionality?

Tags: python, performance, timer, timeit

Do Python timers have the ability to measure multiple intervals in the same timer object? I have a program that loops over thousands of objects and performs several actions e.g.: downloading, process, store, analyze). I'd like to be able to measure the cumulative time of each individual step when performed many times, but in a larger block of code that does other things.

Is there any way to start and then stop (pause) timers, and then re-start them to measure some more time? Something like the following pseudocode?

```
import timeit
download_timer = <create a timer>
processing_timer = <create a timer>

for item_id in big_list_of_items:
    download_timer.start()
    slow_response = download_data(item_id)
    download_timer.pause()
    processing_timer.start()
    munge_data(slow_response)
    processing_timer.pause()

log.debug('Cumulative download time: {} sec'.format(download_timer.elapsed))
log.debug('Cumulative data processing time: {} sec'.format(processing_timer.elapsed))
```

I am currently creating a new timer on each loop and then I have to keep track of the time in multiple variables that I add each increment to. Perusing the docs, it looks like that's the best option, short of creating my own class to do this, but I was hoping someone knows of a simpler way.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html ??

Comment: Would it make sense to calculate the different steps from one general start time? If you work with current time, and save the time used by separate steps you should be able to map the time used by each sub-process, as well as the total time used.

Comment: I ended up just creating 2 small classes to do this. One is a split time for a single time interval. The second is a timers object. It has a dict that tracks as many timers as you want to create. Each timer in the dict is just a list of split objects. A few methods sum up the split times, get averages, or review the individual split times.

It ran ok on 300k loops, but creates so many split objects that it wouldn't scale well. I added the ability to restart a split and keep the cumulative time, so you have the option to just re-use it if you have a massive number of iterations.